# spring-form.tld...where is it?

Tags: spring-mvc

I cannot find this tag lib, i need it because http://www.springframework.org/tags/form
does not work.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-form.tld

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the `spring-webmvc-3.0.x.RELEASE.jar`, of course.

Answer (score 24):

From Spring 3.0 release, both **spring.tld** and **spring-form.tld** can be found in the [spring-webmvc-3.0.x.RELEASE.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar) file.

To use them the JAR file must be in the classpath. Just add the following lines to the JSP files:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

Comment: With the implication that you do not need to directly specify the TLD: it should be found automatically in the JAR?

Comment: As pointed out in http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2012.html#1003416, if uri is a URL, it is located from the packaged libraries. The TLD namespace is the key to search inside this map of available tag libraries.

Answer (score 5):

The spring-webmvc-3.x.x.RELEASE.jar can be included using the following maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Just make sure that the ${spring.version} that you use matches the version of Spring Security (if you are using it) as this may cause version conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, because the springmvc jar was in an EAR library, I had to place the tld files under the WEB-INF folder, and everything is working now

Answer (score 0):

1. spring-from.tld path in org.springframework.web.servlet-version.jar meta-inf
2. org.springframework.web.servlet.version.jar dependent on org.springframework.web-version.jar.
   just download both jars..paste in lib folder.
3. in jsp add the below line:

   ```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
   ```