# JSP form input maxlength not working on number type

Tags: java, html, validation, jsp

I'm using `jsp` `<form:input>` tag for input the data on `jsp` form. The requirement is to limit length of input field and be able to input only numbers.

The following tag works for limiting length of the input string, however I'm able to input any symbols here:

```
<form:input path="somePath" code="someCode" maxlength="3"/>
```

And when I use type `number`, `maxlength` attribute doesn't work and there is no limit on input field, however I'm limited to number only:

`<form:input path="somePath" code="someCode" maxlength="3" type="number"/>`

Is there a way to have input field limited in maximum length and to numbers only? Can't figure out why the line above doesn't work.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element).

Comment: Well, JSP form:input does not understands HTML type="number" attribute, it will always create type="text" input field.

Comment: form:input isn't an html tag as @Andrew S shows (the html tag is input with type=text) form:input is a custom tag from the spring-form.tld, which is part of Spring MVC.  Do you have the tld present, and are you referencing it in your JSP as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900689/spring-form-tld-where-is-it?

Comment: @MichaelPeacock : I know its Spring-Form and I was also saying in the same context. I think there is no way, you could create a type="number" input field using `<form:input ... />`
Ref : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.input

Comment: @Yuriy : I think you'll have to do this validation in Javascript at client side. :/

Comment: @MichaelPeacock yes, I do have `spring-form.tld` in `spring-webmvc` dependency.

Comment: @DaveRanjan That's a bad news. However, the interesting thing that if I use both attributes `type="number"` and `maxlength` separately - it works. So I think `type=number` is supported, but seems it's `maxlength` attribute is not working for some reason.

Comment: Can you paste your HTML, when you use type = "number"

Comment: @DaveRanjan it's very simple, just like `<form:input path="somePath" code="someCode" type="number"/>`. And yes, I see that `type` is not present in `spring-form.tld` but it works.

Comment: You must be having two `type` attribute in your generated HTML, one with `number` and other with `text` right?

Comment: @DaveRanjan no, just `number`.

Comment: That's great!! Then you can add min="1" max="999"  or something like this to limit your entry instead of maxLength. I think maxLength will count the char in your input field and not actual limit of your input.

Comment: @DaveRanjan unfortunately, min/max does not limit the value too. You can try yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469362/1889928) for HTML5, I was able to solve this on `JSP` page in the following way:

```
<form:input maxlength="3" type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
```

As of the type `number` - it is supported by `<form:input>` tag, however there is no way to limit it in length.

Answer (score 0):

Spring `<form:input />` tag doesnt have any attribute named type and the type=number used in your code belongs to [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) input tag

The best way I can think of is to have this validation using Javascript.

Spring form tld lists the valid attributes of form:input element [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.input)